# How to define custom principal class in Elytron WildFly 26.1?

Tags: security, authentication, wildfly, principal, elytron

In legacy system is used dedicated login-module with custom principal class defined in security domain used by application, like below (JBoss 7.2)

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2">
        <security-domains>
            <security-domain name="other-security-domain" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="com.xxx.OtherLoginModule" flag="requisite">
                        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        <module-option name="principalClass" value="com.xxx.OtherPrincipal"/>
                    </login-module>
```

How the corresponding configuration should be done on Wildfly 26.1/Elytron ?
I looked through the documentation 26.1/WildFly_Elytron_Security, (in particular, chapter '18. Migrate Legacy Security to Elytron Security') but found no solution.

Additional problems:

- documentation point to subsystem security/security-domain but in CLI i see only security-management (can't run legacy jaas module based on that doc)
- no any example with custom principal class (base problem)

Answer (score 0):

the login modules should be migrated to an existing security realms if possible, if that is not an option you can implement a custom security realm like mentioned in this [blog](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jbossas/jboss-security/how-to-create-a-custom-elytron-realm/) . Last option is using jaas-realm described [here](https://wildfly-security.github.io/wildfly-elytron/blog/jaas-realm/).

For the custom principal, depending on your use case, it might not be possible, see this unresolved issue https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFCORE-5809 .

But it is possible to instead configure [SecurityIdentity](https://wildfly-security.github.io/wildfly-elytron/documentation/api/current/org/wildfly/security/auth/server/SecurityIdentity.html)'s attributes with the information you want to store in the principal. Then you can obtain these security identity attributes in your application with the [method](https://wildfly-security.github.io/wildfly-elytron/documentation/api/current/org/wildfly/security/auth/server/SecurityIdentity.html#getAttributes()) `SecurityDomain.getCurrent().getCurrentSecurityIdentity().getAttributes()`. Depending on your use case this might be an alternative.